# synchronise two coordinate planes

Tags: 3d

So i have two coordinate planes. One is player and mouse click position relative to player. Other is the world map.

I need to find the point on the world map, where the mouse clicks.

The map is generated from a 64*64 heightmap, so for now i want to find the mouse click inside the 64*64 bounds.

Im having trouble determining the coordinates at the world map, where the mouse clicked.

[image: upper - player and mouse click, lower - world map]

The map has a multiplier of 10. Im not really sure how it is applied, but when it is 10, the world map is in bounds -10,-10 to 10, 10. When it is 20, it is in -20,-20 to 20, 20, when 50 then in -50,-50 to 50,50. Those are click coordinates in relation to player.

To get the world vertex i need to supply a coordinate (0-63, 0-63).

How do i transform the mouse click coordinates so that they are aproppriate to the world map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like simple multiplication & division, no?

```
float2 mapHalfExtents = new float2(10.0f, 10.0f);
int2 mapVertexCount = new int2(64, 64);

int2 GetClosestVertexCoordinates(float2 clickedWorldPoint) {
    // Reduce to the range -0.5...0.5
    float2 normalizedPosition = clickedWorldPoint / (2.0f * mapHalfExtents);

    // Shift to 0...1 (placing the bottom-left corner at the origin)
    normalizedPosition += new float2(0.5f, 0.5f);

    // Map to the range 0...64
    float2 mapSpace = normalizedPosition * mapVertexCount;

    return RoundToInt2(mapSpace);
}
```